# Differences in SVM performance

Tags: svm

Why would a polynomial SVM have better performance than a linear SVM but the same performance as a radial SVM?

Answer (score 3):

If the performance with a linear kernel is bad, it means the data is not separable in input space (assuming a classication context). The feature spaces induced by more complex kernels (such as polynomial or RBF) *can* lead to linear separability.

The feature space of an RBF kernel is more complex than both linear and polynomial (in fact, both linear and degree-2 polynomial are degenerate versions of RBF). Hence, if a polynomial kernel can make the data separable, an appropriate RBF kernel can too.

Comment: I agree with this nice answer by Marc.